# How to combine session between facebook login and native login in a website

Tags: facebook, session, web, authentication, facebook-login

I have a website with user login system. Now i want to integrate my website with Facebook, so user can login to my website with their Facebook account. I have read a lot of tutorial about integrating Facebook to website, and now I've been able to implement Facebook connect on "sample webpage". But now, how to combine/merge my real website with Facebook connect? How about the session, user database, etc (all related to user login system). Any help, answer, explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the idea, with facebook login, you can get a lot of information about the user, like `name`, `first_name`, `last_name`, etc. You may took the facebook `name` from the user as his username in your website. And you can take `first_name` as his password (but it's not save), better you create random characters and encrypt it. 
Hope it can help.